# Convert an int(number) to a list ,the int number could be negative in python

Tags: python, list

I just want to know if there is a simple way to convert an int(negative number) to a list

Example

a = -2021

result : [-2,0,2,1]

def numberToList(n):

```
# base case
if n == 0:
    return []

# recurse
return numberToList(n // 10) + [ n % 10 ]
```

def numberInput(n):

```
if n < 0:
    n = numberToList(abs(n))
    n[0] = n[0] * -1
    return n
else:
    return numberToList(n)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: just convert to the positive equivalent to int and multiply the output with -1

Comment: To expand a bit on the comment above, as it stands, the question shows no proposed solution, just asking for an answer. If you can show what you've tried and help us see what in particular causes confusion for you, we would be glad to help.

Comment: Hint: `r"(-?\d)"`

Comment: `list(map(int, re.findall(r"(-?\d)", s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function like this:

```
from typing import List

def num_list(num: int) -> List[int]:
    if num == 0:
        return []
    ns = [int(i) for i in str(num).lstrip('-')]
    if num < 0:
        ns[0] *= -1
    return ns
```

Comment: "the int number *could* be negative in python" - Your code will not work if the number doesn't start out negative